# Cartopy cannot read US census files

Tags: python, cartopy

I'm trying to get shapes of US counties into Python.

My approach was to manually download the shape files from the [US census](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_counties.html) and then import them using

```
from cartopy.io import shapereader
shapereader.Reader('shapefiles/cb_2014_us_county_20m.shp')
```

But I keep getting the same error for different resolutions:

```
ValueError: Unsupported shape type: 15
```

Googling this error yielded nothing - what does this mean, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a limitation in Cartopy.  If you look at the source file referenced in the full traceback, you can see that in the `Reader` class there is the following code:

```
    shapeType = reader.shapeType
    self._geometry_factory = GEOMETRY_FACTORIES.get(shapeType)
    if self._geometry_factory is None:
        raise ValueError('Unsupported shape type: %s' % shapeType)
```

And if we look at the value of `GEOMETRY_FACTORIES`, we see:

```
GEOMETRY_FACTORIES = {
    shapefile.POINT: _create_point,
    shapefile.POLYLINE: _create_polyline,
    shapefile.POLYGON: _create_polygon,
}
```

So, Cartopy only works with with POINT (type 1), POLYLINE (type 3) and POLYGON (type 5) shapes.

To read these files with Cartopy, you would need to convert the POLYGONZ shapes (type 15) into POLYGON shapes.  I believe you can do this with the `ogr2ogr` tool that is part of the [gdal](http://www.gdal.org/) package:

```
ogr2ogr -nlt POLYGON cb_2014_us_county_20m-POLYGON.shp cb_2014_us_county_20m.shp
```